# SQL Query to compare 2 weeks

Tags: sql, visual-studio, t-sql

I've got to design a query in visual studio where I have 2 data sets.

basically it goes like this.

I want to compare this weeks call total to last week per country calling.
the only thing is last weeks calls may have come from 20 diff countries while this weeks might only have come from 15. 
How can I make the query such that the 20 countries will show up for both while having "0" value in for countries that do not appear this week.

below is my query:

```
Select country, 
        Sum(Case When actstatus in (5,105) Then 1 Else 0 End) As TotalCalls,
        Sum(Case When actstatus = 105 Then 1 Else 0 End) As FailedCalls
From  termactivity(nolock)  
    INNER JOIN termconfig(NOLOCK) ON cfgterminalID = actterminalID 
    INNER JOIN Country (nolock) on country = cycode

Where  actstatus in (5,105)
and  (actTerminalDateTime BETWEEN @StartDate-7 AND @EndDate-7)

Group By country
order By country asc
```

When Act status = 105 it means the call was not completed and when it = 5 it means the call was successful. I am doing this to get a successful call % rate per week.
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: can you post termactivity and termconfig tables' structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to perform separate queries for two weeks, and you want both queries to produce rows for all countries, regardless of whether all countries had any calls. To achieve this, you need to use LEFT OUTER JOINS. The below code should guarantee that every country found in the Country table has a row, even if both sums are 0.

```
SELECT country, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN actstatus IN (5,105) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TotalCalls,
    SUM(CASE WHEN actstatus = 105 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FailedCalls
FROM Country (NOLOCK)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN termconfig (NOLOCK) ON country = cycode
    LEFT OUTER JOIN termactivity (NOLOCK) ON cfgterminalID = actterminalID 
WHERE (actTerminalDateTime BETWEEN @StartDate-7 AND @EndDate-7)

GROUP BY country
ORDER BY country ASC
```

If this was not what you wanted, perhaps you need to clarify your question. Many others have assumed that you want to combine the results into a single query.

Comment: Hi.Thanks for that but ya I do want it all in  the one query.

Comment: I think the OP was talking about all countries *referenced within two weeks*, rather than all countries available. That is, some countries might appear only this week, others only last week, but the OP wants both, as well as those that appeared both this *and* last weeks. On the other hand, assuming `actTerminalDateTime` is a column in `termactivity`, your `WHERE` clause effectively makes your outer joins *inner*, so the results will possibly include only the relevant countries.

Answer (score 4):

Apply the same logic as you did to total calls and failed calls as you did to the this week and last week.

```
SELECT  country, 
        COUNT(CASE WHEN actTerminalDateTime < @StartDate THEN 1 END) [LastWeekTotalCalls],
        COUNT(CASE WHEN ActStatus = 105 AND actTerminalDateTime < @StartDate THEN 1 END) [LastWeekFailedCalls],
        COUNT(CASE WHEN actTerminalDateTime >= @StartDate THEN 1 END) [ThisWeekTotalCalls],
        COUNT(CASE WHEN ActStatus = 105 AND actTerminalDateTime >= @StartDate THEN 1 END) [ThisWeekFailedCalls]
FROM    termactivity (NOLOCK)  
        INNER JOIN termconfig (NOLOCK) 
            ON cfgterminalID = actterminalID 
        INNER JOIN Country (NOLOCK) 
            ON country = cycode
WHERE   actstatus in (5,105)
AND     actTerminalDateTime BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -7, @StartDate) AND @EndDate
GROUP BY country
ORDER BY country ASC
```

I've also tidied up your query slightly, for example there is no point in specifying

```
WHEN ActStatus IN (5, 105) ...
```

When your WHERE clause already limits all results to 5, 105, therefore this is a redundant predicate in your case expression